# Issues creating cloudformation resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I've been playing around with creating a test Cloudformation resources and it's not been so straight forward.
I've hit a stumbling block and not sure  how to resolve it.
As part of my test application I want to have my resource create a lambda.  But when I put the following into my code.

```
def create_lambda(session:SessionProxy,identifier:str):
 ARCHIVE = './lambdas/Hello.zip'
 BUCKET_NAME = 'hello-function-910283989807'
 ZIP_NAME = 'Hello.zip'
 REGION = 'us-east-2'
 s3_client = session.client("s3", region_name=REGION)
 s3_client.create_bucket(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME,CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint': REGION})
 s3_client.put_object(Body=ARCHIVE, Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key=ZIP_NAME)
```

Even if I don't run this function, after submitting the resource and upon creating a test stack using this resource I get the following error appear in the cloudformation stack events.

```
Lambda function handler threw an uncaught exception: Unable to import module 'xxxxx_notifications_app.handlers': No module named 'xxxxxx_notifications_app'
```

I can't make sense of this.  It seems that just having the put_object in my code causes this to occur?

Comment: It seems to be attempting to run the Lambda function, but is failing in an import. Is your Lambda function importing anything? Where is the handler in that function?

Comment: The lambda function it is referring to is not mine. It's the one which cloudformation runs to create my resource. In fact I have removed the part of the code which creates the lambda. It seems to be the put object that is the problem. But I don't know how to resolve

Comment: The `put_object()` would not produce that error message. What makes you think that the function is being successfully started? Can you see any debug output for the Lambda function in CloudWatch Logs? Also, that is an incomplete function for a Custom Resource -- the handler is wrong (or missing) and it is not calling using `cfn-response` (See: [AWS CloudFormation custom resource creation with Python, AWS Lambda, and crhelper | Infrastructure & Automation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/aws-cloudformation-custom-resource-creation-with-python-aws-lambda-and-crhelper/))